# Symfony 3.4 multi tenant connection setup

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, multi-tenant

I'm reworking an old codebase to work with multi tenant connections and I need some help.
The current situation is accounts are stored each in their own databases on a single server. Accounts also have their own defined entity manager and doctrine connection, and this works fine.

Now I want to break that up by putting the account databases in their own separate server, or even multiple servers. For this the server name for each account will be stored in the landlord database.

What would be the best way to make Symfony be able to switch the connection in the account's entity manager dynamically?
Should I define different connections for each server, or is a general 'account' connection sufficient where just the hostname will be able to be switched out on demand and the connection recreated based on which current account is active, and the stored hostname of it?

Is such a thing possible? This is on Symfony 3.4.

Comment: You should check doctrine wrapper_class configuration : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html There is a lack of documentation on this subject but there is a lot of chance that this will help you

Comment: I don't think it will help me. At the connection level I cannot access repositories or inject my current user/account model to fetch information. Ideally if possible I have to wrap around a factory, inject my model and adjust how the connection is made but I don't know how or what.

Comment: The wrapper_connection will be a service. You can inject whatever you want in it. There will be at least 2 connections, one for storing your database connetion informations and the other that will switch. So you can inject the entityManager (or depending repository) of the first one in your wrapper connection

Comment: Like Florian already mentioned, it's possible using a `wrapper_class`. If you want, share your `doctrine.yaml` to guide you in the right direction.